# Prove that $p$-adic norm is an ultrametric

Tags: general-topology, analysis, proof-verification, proof-writing, p-adic-number-theory

**Definition**. A metric $\rho$ on a set $X$ is an ultrametric if it satisfies the inequality
$$
\rho(x, y) \leq \max \{\rho(x, z), \rho(z, y)\}
$$
for all $x, y, z .$

**Question**. Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the set of rational numbers and let $p$ be a prime number.
We define a mapping $u$ from $\mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ as follows:
$$
u(x, y)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}{0} & {, \text { if } x=y} \\ {p^{-\alpha}} & {, \text { if } x \neq y}\end{array}\right.
$$

where $y-x=\frac{p^{\alpha} m}{n}, m$ and $n$ are relatively prime integers not divisible
by $p .$ Show that $u$ is an ultrametric.

My Answer. If $x \neq y$ then $u(x, y)=p^{-\alpha}$ where $y-x=p^{\alpha} \frac{m}{n}$, $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime integers not divisible by $p$.

Assume $u(x,z)=p^{-\gamma}$ where $z-x=p^\gamma \dfrac{c} {d}$, $c$ and $d$ are relatively prime integers not divisible by $p$, and

$u(z,y)=p^{-\beta}$ where $y-z=p^\beta \dfrac{a} {b}$, $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime integers not divisible by $p$.

WLOG we assume that $\beta < \gamma$, then

$$y-x=y-z+z-x=p^\beta \dfrac {a} {b} + p^{\gamma} \dfrac {c} {d}$$

$$
p^{\alpha} \frac{m}{n}=p^{\beta} \frac{a}{b}+p^{\gamma} \frac{c}{d}
$$

$$
=p^\beta (\dfrac {a} {b} + p^{\gamma - \beta} \dfrac {c} {d})
$$

$$
p^\beta (\dfrac {ad+p^{\gamma - \beta}bc} {bd} ).
$$

Consider $ad+p^{\gamma - \beta}bc=r$ and $bd=s$. So we can see that $r$ and $s$ are not divisible by $p$. Hence $\alpha=\beta$. Then since $\alpha=\beta < \gamma$, we get

$$p^{-\alpha}=p^{-\beta}<p^{-\gamma},$$

then $$u(x,y)=u(z,y)<u(x,z),$$

hence we can say that $$u(x, y) \leq \max \{u(x, z), u(z, y)\}.$$

Please, may you check my answer? May you give me a feedback for the answer? Thanks!

Comment: It is not necessarily true that $r$ is not divisible by $p$. In fact it is not necessarily true that $u(x, y) = \min(u(x, z), u(y, z))$ even if $u(x, y) \leq \max(u(x, z), u(y, z))$. For example, consider $x = 3, y = 1, z = 4$ and $p = 2$ in the $2$-adics. Moreover, $\beta \lt \gamma$ implies $p^{-\beta} \gt p^{-\gamma}$ which is the other way around from what you wrote.

Comment: I think you're almost there. Taking into account @TobErnack's last remark, what you actually need to show is $\alpha \ge \beta$. And for that, it should be enough that $bd$ is not divisible by $p$.